# Achievements implementation in Android app

Tags: android, achievements

I just wonder if Android SDK has special tool for achievements implementing. I want to add some in my game project, but don't know the best way to do it.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of Google specific release, but a lot of Android games is utilizing [Open Feint](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/getting-started-with-openfeint-sdk-for-android-1-8/). With Open Feint, you can provide achievement and rewards for your game.

For specific page for how to implement achievements in OpenFeint, see [the OpenFeint Tutorial](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/getting-started-with-of-android-1-10-2-add-openfeint-features-to-your-game/)

Comment: open feint is [dead](http://www.polygon.com/2012/11/16/3655496/openfeint-shutting-down-dec-14-could-disrupt-ios-android-games) now :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Skiller and you can easily implement achievements using the Skiller SDK.
The [Skiler SDK](http://www.skiller-games.com) allows you to define achievements for your game and use this simple API to unlock it:

```
SKApplication.getInstance().getGameManager().unlockAchievement(achievementId, callback);
```

You can also check out our [wiki pages](http://wiki.skiller-games.com).

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com/achievements), which provides a simple achievement system (very similar to the OpenFeint suggestion by momo).  Define the achievements online, unlock them in your game.